# Como finalizar uma tela de loading após executar promisses no Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic, promises

Bom dia.

Estou com um dúvida, tenho um controller que busca alguns dados de um webservice rest, e os persiste no banco de dados do aparelho(ionic), para efetuar a busca dos dados, estou usando 'promises'.

Quando inicia a busca eu abro uma tela de Loading, e gostaria que após terminar  todas as execuções das promises, fechar a tela de loading.

> Estou fazendo da seguinte forma:

```
LoadingService.show();

var promise = function1.promise();
promise.then(function (result) {
    if (result) {
        MeuService.insert(result);
    }
});

var promise2 = function2.promise();
promise2.then(function (result) {
    if (result) {
        MeuService.insert(result);
    }
});

var promise3 = function3.promise();
promise3.then(function (result) {
    if (result) {
        MeuService.insert(result);
     // Já tentei deixar aqui tbm..
    // LoadingService.hide();
    }
});

//??
LoadingService.hide();
```

O problema é que logo depois de iniciar, ele já fecha o loading, e continua a execução das promisses.
 Onde estou errando?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o método all do $q, que é o service que provê promises no angular 1.

Da seguinte maneira:

```js
LoadingService.show();

function insertResult(result) {
  MyService.insert(result);
}

var promise1 = function1.promise();
var promise2 = function2.promise();
var promise3 = function3.promise();

$q.all([
  promise1.then(insertResult),
  promise2.then(insertResult),
  promise3.then(insertResult)
]).then(function() {
  LoadingService.hide();
});
```

Dessa maneira o `LoadingService.hide` somente será executado após todas as promises serem resolvidas.